# Help excel table not transferring to Arc correctly!

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, excel

New to GIS and Ive been trying to figure this out for a while. I have an excel sheet with CT names such as 0128.03, 0128.04, starting from 0001.00 and up. Not all CTs have .01, .02 at the end just .00. anyways when I transfer it to a dbf and open it up in arc the field shows with no decimals. I did a custom format for 0000.00 but for some reason 0128.03 shows up twice and I was missing 0128.04. I realized the duplicate of 0128.03 actually was 0128.03999999 and should be 0128.04 theres others doing the same thing as well. I have no clue how to get 128.04 or stop the continous decimal. Do I format the cells a certain way in Excel? I need these values to be correct so i can join the CT field with another table.

Comment: instead of saving to a dbf, try saving to a 97-2003 .xls file.

Comment: I saved it as a .xls first then export from arc as DBF. and CT is the field head and the numbers are the values

Comment: You might find my explanation at http://www.quantdec.com/SYSEN597/GTKAV/section4/chapter_15a.htm#Recipe to be helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off is exporting the data as a CSV then in ArcGIS export that file to a DBF? Meanwhile, do a table join by CT_ID for the whole layer and then export the joined layer as its own layer?

Answer (score 3):

Try saving as CSV and see all the answers and comments on [How to best prepare csv files for use in arcgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45050/how-to-best-prepare-csv-files-for-use-in-arcgis). Once it is imported into ArcGIS you can export/convert to dbf or gdb or other table format.

Answer (score 1):

you might try formatting the column as text, which will be necessary to preserve the leading 0s.