# How to generate sequential numbers for list of input table fields written to a text file (ArcMap script tool)?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, for-loop, autoincrement, schema

In order for a script tool I'm writing in ArcMap to read fields in a source CSV correctly as text, I need to automate the writing of a shema.ini file in the source directory. In order to do that I need to write a list of fields from an input table to a text file with sequential column names, i.e., "Col1", "Col2", etc. before each field name from the list.  Is there a way to insert a sequential number function into a for loop expression that will increment each field name in the list?

```
addressTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inputDir = os.path.dirname(addressTable)
schemaFile = str(inputDir) + "\schema.ini"
fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(addressTable)

with open(schemaFile, 'w') as f:
    for field in fieldList:
       f.write("Col" + ???? + "=" + field.name + " Text Width 128\n")
```

This is an example of what I need to get to:

```
Col1=UID Text Width 128
Col2=Address Text Width 128
Col3=City Text Width 128
Col4=State Text Width 128
Col5=ZIP Text Width 128
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index a counter.  For example:

```
counter = 0
for i in range(5):
    counter +=1
    print('Col' + str(counter))
```

This code returns or prints out....

```
Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4
Col5
```

So in your case you can increment the counter by 1 for each field, convert that to a string and do the concantenation.

```
counter = 0
with open(schemaFile, 'w') as f:
    for field in fieldList:
       counter +=1
       f.write("Col" + str(counter) + "=" + field.name + " Text Width 128\n")
```

Comment: This situation is one reason why [enumerate() - Built-in Functions - Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) exists.